# Incorrect rendering of Javascript by PyQt5 QWebEngine

Tags: python, pyqt5, qwebengineview

I'm building a browser using PyQt5. It's a rather huge code, but this is the main problem I'm facing. The code is this:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

web = QWebEngineView()
file = open("example.html", "r")
html = file.read()
web.setHtml(html)
file.close()
web.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The problem is that the rendering is rather strange.[Image of the rendering is here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tazTf.png)
The contents of the example.html file:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head><title>JS Example</title></head>
<h1>JS example</h1>
<p><button type = 'button' onclick = "document.getElementById('tobeshown').style.display='block'">Show hidden parts of this page</button></p>
<p id = 'tobeshown' style = "display:none">
Peekaboo!
</p>
<p>
<button type = 'button' onclick="document.getElementById('tobeshown').style.display='none'">Hide it!</button>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The expected output(this is in Mozilla Firefox browser): [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwawy.png)

Can anyone tell me why the PyQt5 rendering engine produces those symbols at the top? And what can I do to resolve it?  Thank you very much.

Comment: Validate your HTML, it seems to be broken: `</button><p>`that should be `</button></p>`?!

Comment: Sorry @MauriceMeyer that still generates the same output. Thanks for pointing out though.

Comment: Opening <body>-Tag is missing as well, fix all markup errors and it is going to work as expected :)

Comment: @MauriceMeyer it seems that the issue is with python file reading and not the rendering. When I add the line `print(html)` It outputs `ï»¿<!Doctype html>` and so on.

Comment: As i said the HTML is broken, so remove 'hidden' unicode characters from there or try to save the HTML as ASCII. This ain't (real) Python, PyQt5 or webkit errors.

Comment: Thank you very much! I changed the fie encoding to UTF-8 and it works perfectly. You could make it an answer and I could accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is not WebEngine's rendering but instead Python's reading of a file. Changing the file's encoding to UTF-8 solved the problem for me.